# in collectionView cell i added cell.alpha but cell.alpha not working

Tags: swift, cell, collectionview

Code:

```
func collectionView(\_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -\> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
cell.alpha = 0
return cell
}
```

`cell.alpha` not working please help

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `alpha` to the cell's content.

```swift
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.3
```